# Mostrar comando executado quando acontecer erro no SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Considerando o seguinte comando executado

```
BEGIN TRY  
    -- Generate a divide-by-zero error.  
    SELECT 1/0;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT  
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  

END CATCH;  
GO
```

A resposta do mesmo será:

```
ErrorNumber
8134

ErrorSeverity
16

ErrorState
1

ErrorProcedure
NULL

ErrorMessage
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

Existe alguma maneira de pegar qual bloco de execução foi executado para gerar esta exceção?

Queria que a resposta fosse:

```
Command

'SELECT 1/0;'
```

Answer (score 3):

Jhonathan, normalmente não é uma saída de erro convencional, mas esse trecho pode te ajudar:

```
BEGIN TRY  
    -- Generate a divide-by-zero error.  

    SELECT 1 / 0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT [qt].text
      FROM [sys].[dm_exec_connections] AS [A]
           CROSS APPLY [sys].[dm_exec_sql_text]([A].[most_recent_sql_handle]) AS [qt]
     WHERE [session_id] = @@SPID;
END CATCH;  
GO
```

Mas na minha opinião, você poderia coletar esses erros de outra forma, em uma auditoria.

[SQLServer: Auditoria de erros de query](http://www.dbinternals.com.br/?p=989)

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução e você criar uma variável para armazenar a descrição do bloco que esta sendo executado e concatenar na mensagem.

```
declare @BlocoExe varchar(max)

BEGIN TRY  
    -- Generate a divide-by-zero error. 
    set @BlocoExe  = 'Bloco exe: SELECT 1/0 - Erro:'; -- descrição do bloco
    SELECT 1/0;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT  
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        , @BlocoExe + ERROR_MESSAGE()  AS ErrorMessage ;  

END CATCH;  
GO
```

Comment: Não dá pra fazer isso, pois a aplicação que irei aplicar este modelo são vários comandos com vários registros.

Comment: sim, mas quantos erros vai retorna? especifique melhor sua pergunta.

Comment: quero que ele retorne quaisquer erros que der.

Comment: E qual o problema?  Só  usar a variável e concatena